# Why does my bar plot in python cut off part of the x variable when plotting?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, seaborn, data-analysis

I am using pycharm to create plots of data, and I am following along a kaggle tutorial of seaborn. The bar plot plots flight delays throughout 12 months, and on the tutorial it shows 1-12 on the x axis, but when I try to execute this in my code in python it shows only up to 11.
I am very new to python, and coding in general and trying to self teach, but I'm having a lot of problems navigating pycharm and solving this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
print("Setup Complete")

flight_delays = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Portfolio Projects\seaborn_work\flight_delays.csv')
print(flight_delays)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.barplot(x=flight_delays.index, y=flight_delays['NK'])
plt.ylabel("Arrival delay (In minutes)")
plt.title("Average Arrival Delay for Spirit Airline Flights, by Month")
plt.show()
```

I have tried using xlim to show all 12 x values, but that does not work for me or I dont understand how to use the command.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/alexisbcook/bar-charts-and-heatmaps/tutorial
here is the link to the tutorial I am following as well.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/alexisbcook/data-for-datavis?select=flight_delays.csv ?

When you read a csv with pandas by default the index will be numbers starting from 0. So if there are 12 months (rows) the index is 0 to 11. Unlike the `Month` column which contains the numbers from 1 to 12.

You can either relace the x argument with the `Month` column instead of the index:

```
sns.barplot(x=flight_delays['Month'], y=flight_delays['NK'])
```

Or you first set the Month column as index and then use the same command you did before:

```
flight_delays.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
sns.barplot(x=flight_delays.index, y=flight_delays['NK'])
```

You could also just explicitly set which column should be used as index column when you use `read_csv`, then you do not have to make any other changes to your code:

```
flight_delays = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\Portfolio Projects\seaborn_work\flight_delays.csv', index_col='Month')
```